# Sort by string equality and then by number in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dynamic, swift3

I would like to sort my array first whether the establishment is closed and then by distance. For example, all the "Closed" establishments should be at the bottom of the dynamic table and then it should sort the remaining ones having the smallest distance at the top. Right now, i have the following code:

```
bars.sort{ (lhs: barStruct, rhs: barStruct) -> Bool in

   if lhs.tonight == "Closed" && rhs.tonight != "Closed"{
       return false
   }
   else {
      return lhs.distance < rhs.distance
   }
```

Right now, this only does it some of the time

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your structs starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: You should post your struct declaration along with your desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider all combinations of Closed & Open, not just `lhs` Closed and `rhs` Open. I think the ordering you are after is:

```
bars.sort { (lhs : barStruct, rhs : barStruct) -> Bool in
   if lhs.tonight == "Closed"
   {
      return false // Closed/Open & Closed/Closed
   }
   else if rhs.tonight == "Closed"
   {
      return true; // Open/Closed
   }
   else
   {
      return lhs.distance < rhs.distance // Open/Open => use distance
   }
}
```

However this does not order the Closed bars in any way, it might be better to order those by distance as well:

```
bars.sort { (lhs : barStruct, rhs : barStruct) -> Bool in
   if lhs.tonight == "Closed"
   {
      if rhs.tonight == "Closed"
      {
         return lhs.distance < rhs.distance // Closed/Closed => use distance
      }
      else
      {
         return false // Closed/Open
      }
   }
   else if rhs.tonight == "Closed"
   {
      return true; // Open/Closed
   }
   else
   {
      return lhs.distance < rhs.distance // Open/Open => use distance
   }
}
```

Now if you had a boolean flag, rather than a string, for Closed/Open you could reduce that to a single if with an xor condition... That is left as an exercise!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You should divide `.tonight` and `.distance` into two sort conditions

```
struct barStruct{
    var tonight : String
    var distance : Int
}

var bars = [barStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 12),
            barStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 20),
            barStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 1),
            barStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 32),
            barStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 11),
            barStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 9),
            barStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 23),
            barStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 56),]

bars.sort { (lhs: barStruct, rhs: barStruct) -> Bool in
    if lhs.tonight == "Closed"{
        if rhs.tonight == "Closed"{
            //both on bottom level, addtionaly sort by distance
            return lhs.distance < rhs.distance
        }else{
            //left on bottom level, right on top level
            return false
        }
    }else{
        if rhs.tonight == "Closed"{
            //left on top level, right on bottom level
            return true
        }else{
            //both on top level, addtionaly sort by distance
            return lhs.distance < rhs.distance
        }
    }
}

print(bars)
```

> [barStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 9), barStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 11), barStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 23), barStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 56), barStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 1), barStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 12), barStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 20), barStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 32)]

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your condition minimal and for two keys `tonight` and `distance`.

1) Make sort `tonight` as ascending order and..

2) Put condition or `distance` as ascending

Ex:

```
struct testStruct {
    var tonight : String
    var distance : Int
}

var list = [testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 1),
            testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 78),
            testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 14),
            testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 36),
            testStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 34),
            testStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 94),
            testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 3),
            testStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 56),]

// sort condition 
let sortedList = list.sorted { (lhs, rhs ) -> Bool in
    if lhs.tonight == rhs.tonight { // If tonight is same then step 2
        return lhs.distance < rhs.distance
    }
    // Follow step 1
    return (lhs.tonight) > (rhs.tonight)
}

print(sortedList)
```

Output:

> [testStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 34), testStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 56), testStruct(tonight: "Open", distance: 94), testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 1), testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 3), testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 14), testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 36), testStruct(tonight: "Closed", distance: 78)]